# Why I am not getting values in my page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, master-detail

below is my class, 
Can you help where i am going wrong,
I am not getting values in my page

```
public class DeleteFlag
{
public Property__c prop{get; set;}
Public Unit__c unts{get;set;}
public List<Unit__c> Records {get; set;}
public DeleteFlag(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        prop=new Property__c();
        unts = new unit__c(); 
        Records = [select Name,Property_Unit__c FROM Unit__c WHERE 
        Property_Unit__c = :Prop.Id];
        system.debug(prop.Id);
     }
```

Comment: You are initializing `prop` in constructor and then you are referring it in SOQL, How it would suppose to have the id.

Comment: Please accept the answer if that solved your problem to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
prop = new Property__c();
```

You're creating a brand new, blank record that doesn't have an ID. Instead, get the record from your standard controller:

```
prop = (Property__c)controller.getRecord();
```